# Workspaces missing in ubuntu 16.04. No appearance preference in settings.

Tags: unity, 16.04, workspaces, appearance

Recently installed ubuntu 16.04, and could not find a way to enable workspaces. There is no option called appearance in my settings[image: my settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i figured out what to do in this case.
I did a

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and it came back. But while doing this some of the unwanted softwares that in uninstalled earlier also came back (like thunderbird, libreoffice math etc)

Comment: It is possible that in removing some (of those ?) packages eralier, you also accidentally got rid of some dependencies related to the settings  which were missing. Look out for all the dependencies affected by purging or removing certain bundled packages if you insist on removing them.

Comment: i only uninstalled thunderbird, libreoffice math, stock browser, gedit and the default music and video players.

Comment: **"*Only*"** ???  Hahaha ! We'd have to  propose a new logarithmic (open) scale going from "none" to "very many" just for you. What you removed was **a lot**.

Comment: really! I thought all of these are third party stuffs, so no direct interaction with the OS

Comment: You somehow caused unity-control-center to be removed, what's in your screenshot is gnome-control-center. Next time pay closer attention and or use synaptic so you can easily parse your history & see what was done.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

`sudo apt install unity-control-center`

For some reason i had previously installed `gnome-control-center`

They look almost identical, but the "Appearance" icon is missing.